# undefined symbol: gdVersionString

Tags: php, apache, magento, gd

I am getting an error while starting httpd-2.4.27 with php-7.0.22 for Magento 2.1.6 on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP1. I have manually compiled httpd-2.4.27 and all other modules listed below and all compiled without any error.

No errors when compiling PHP with httpd using below script.

```
./configure --prefix=/app/php-7.0.22 --with-apxs2=/app/httpd-2.4.27/bin/apxs --with-config-file-path=/app/php-7.0.22 --with-libxml-dir=/app/libxml2-2.9.4 --enable-mbstring --enable-zip --with-openssl --with-xsl=/app/libxslt-1.1.29 --enable-intl --with-icu-dir=/app/icu58 --with-jpeg-dir=/app/jpeg-9b  --with-png-dir=/app/libpng-1.6.30 --with-zlib-dir=/app/zlib-1.2.11 --with-webp-dir=/app/libwebp-0.6.0  --with-mcrypt=/app/libmcrypt-2.5.8  --with-gd=/app/libgd-2.2.4 

Error appears while starting httpd

./apachectl start

httpd: Syntax error on line 152 of /app/httpd-2.4.27/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/libphp7.so into server: /app/httpd-2.4.27/modules/libphp7.so: undefined symbol: gdVersionString
```

Comment: Please post your httpd.conf file

Comment: Here is the file --> [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m96tjwp88i99nnq/httpd.conf?dl=0)

Also the error comes only when php is compiled using --with-gd=/app/libgd-2.2.4